# Add a group id column using row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #Test (reference int identity,id int,dataset varchar(10),primary key (reference))
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (1,'System1')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (2,'System10')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (9,'System3')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (0,'')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (8,'System6')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (19,'System7')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (0,'')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (55,'System10')
insert into #Test (id,dataset) values (62,'System4')
```

I am looking for an output like this:

[image]

An ID of zero separates the groups.   I have tried this so far:

```
select * from (
select  row_number() over (order by reference) as groupid, #test.* from #test
```

However, the groupid does not reset when a zero is reached in the ID column.

I realize this is bad design.  The table was created by an external company.  I am just querying it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN 1 END) 
                OVER (ORDER BY reference),0) + 1 AS GroupID
FROM #Test
```

The query uses `SUM OVER` with an `ORDER BY` clause, to calculate a running total of the number of `0` values. If we add `1` to this running total we obtain the required `GroupID` value.

**Note:** This version of `SUM` is available from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

**Edit:**

You can simulate `SUM OVER` with an `ORDER BY` clause in older versions of SQL Server using `OUTER APPLY` as in the query below:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       x.cnt + 1 AS GroupID
FROM #Test t1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(cASE WHEN id = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt
             FROM #Test t2
             WHERE t2.reference <= t1.reference) AS x
```

Comment: Nice! I like the simplicity of this solution (at least when compared to what I started thinking about when reading the question...)

Comment: @w0051977 Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012, the simplest way by using CTE.You can use this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY reference),0)+ 1 AS GroupID,
      ID AS ID,
      dataset AS Dataset
  FROM 
     #Test 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE ID !=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, the simplest way is to use `outer apply`.  I would do this as:

```
SELECT cume.GroupID, t.*
FROM #Test t OUTER APPLY
      (SELECT COUNT(*) as GroupID
       FROM #Test t2
       WHERE t2.reference <= t.reference AND t2.id = 0
      ) cume
WHERE t.id <> 0;
```

Note that the OP doesn't seem to want rows with `0`s in the output.  It is safe to exclude them from the outer query.

One alternative method would use recursive CTEs, but that might be troublesome on large tables.